# Postgresql: LEFT JOIN is not working

Tags: postgresql, many-to-many, left-join

I have two tables tb1 and tb2 with mant-to-many relation:

```
tb1:
id  | code
-------------
1   | 6%
2   | 12%
```

---

```
tb2:
id  | code
-------------
1   | code_001
2   | code_002
```

---

```
tb2_has_tb1:
id_tb2  | id_tb1   | money
---------------------------
1       | 1        | 250.0
1       | 2        | 300.0
2       | 1        | 100.0
```

The result I want to get is :

```
code_tb2  |code_tb1  | money
------------------------------
code_001  |6%        | 250.0
code_001  |12%       | 300.0
code_002  |6%        | 100.0
code_002  |12%       | 0.0   //----I want to display this row with zero if there is no join
```

So what I did is a select query with left join like this:

```
SELECT tb2.code as code_tb2, tb1.code as code_tb1, money
FROM tb1 LEFT JOIN tb2_has_tb1 ON (tb1.id = id_tb1)
LEFT JOIN tb2 ON (tb2.id = id_tb2)
```

but I keep getting this result:

```
code_tb2  |code_tb1  | money
------------------------------
code_001  |6%        | 250.0
code_001  |12%       | 300.0
code_002  |6%        | 100.0
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to retain all possible combinations of id values from `tb1` and `tb2`, one option would be to `CROSS JOIN` these tables.  Then, `LEFT JOIN` this result to the bridge table `tb2_has_tb1` to retain every relationship.

```
SELECT tb2.code AS code_tb2, tb1.code AS code_tb1,
    COALESCE(t.money, 0.0) AS money
FROM tb1 CROSS JOIN tb2
LEFT JOIN tb2_has_tb1 t
    ON tb1.id = t.id_tb1 AND tb2.id = t.id_tb2
```

Comment: What COALESCE do ?

Comment: `COALESCE(t.money, 0.0)` will use the value `t.money` if it be _not_ null, and it will return `0.0` when it is null.  This is how you can detect that the join did not happen.